# PHP REGEX remove +X%

Tags: php, regex

I have strings like

```
+200% just string
+20% other string
+350% other etc ..
```

I need a regex to remove `+X%` and get the following string only.
I tried it with

```
echo trim(preg_replace("/[+][0-9][%]/","",$str));
```

but that gives the same output as `echo $str`.

Comment: Do you think maybe it would help people help you if you told them what the error actually is?  -1.

Comment: Why do you use `[+]` and `[%]` instead of `+` and `%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `+` after `[0-9]`, meaning "one or more":

```
preg_replace("/[+][0-9]+%/", "", $str)
```